# Error in hive query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I want update a metastore table and i have a .sh with: 
`hive 
load data inpath '/user/cloudera/Divisas/Barril_Brent.csv;`

But when the terminal execute hive don´t take the next instruction that will update the data of the table

I had thought something like this:

`hive -e 'load data inpath '/user/cloudera/Divisas/Barril_Brent.csv' overwrite into table BarrilBrent';`

But dont works because catch only hive and It gets into the command line program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the file exists in specified `hdfs` location (`/user/cloudera/Divisas/Barril_Brent.csv`).
if the file is in linux / unix file system then add `local` key word just before `inpath` keyword( just like `local inpath` )

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Executing the hive query - starts"
hive -e "load data inpath '/user/cloudera/Divisas/Barril_Brent.csv' into overwrite into table BarrilBrent"
echo "Executing the hive query - ends"
```

Comment: Thanks with "..." works!!  this is possible or any way to get?:  load data inpath ´x/x/x/x´ overwrite into table x  where value>y  in other way, load the data with conditions?

Comment: @MiguelAngelSanchez - you can create partitions for the table based on column(s). And load the updated data only into that partition. Following is an example.

`LOAD DATA  INPATH '/user/data/updated_california-employees'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE employees
PARTITION (country = 'US', state = 'CA');`